# I Can't figure out how to write a Test to pass a Composable Test in Android

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I took a [Codelab Lunch-tray App](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-navigation#4) it had no Tests so I tried to create these tests to practice. I tried to create testcases for it based on another codelab [Codelab Cupcake](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-test-cupcake?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-test-cupcake#4)
The way these 2 projects differ is that on the second codelab(Lunch-tray) the "Next" button is in uppercase.
Which I can not figure out how to write a test to make it pass.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
val myNextButton = composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.btn_next).uppercase()
composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(myNextButton).performClick()
navController.assertCurrentRouteName(LixoPlayScreen.SideDishScreen.name)
```

This seems to work, but on mouse over activity I see this message

> Avoid calling often as it can involve synchronization and can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onNodeWithText` method you can set the **`ignoreCase`** to **`true`**.

Something like:

```
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(
          text = composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.next),
          ignoreCase = true)
        .performClick()
```

In the codelab, to use the `onNodeWithStringId` method just change:

```
fun <A : ComponentActivity> AndroidComposeTestRule<ActivityScenarioRule<A>, A>.onNodeWithStringId(
   @StringRes id: Int
): SemanticsNodeInteraction = onNodeWithText(activity.getString(id),ignoreCase = true)
```